# SSL/TLS connection error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having problems installing packages in Visual Studio 2010. When I run the Package Manager Console it displays the following error:

```
PM> Install-Package wpf.themes
Install-Package : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  wpf.themes
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Either the other end doesn't support SSL/TSL or don't have a valid certificate, or the certificate is self-signed. That's my guesses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read this [article](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=89943.30.) this may help you.
Thus might help Good Luck!

Try following these steps:

- Download the Equifax Secure Certificate Authority certificate (http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/) and install it into your System.
- Add imap.gmail.com to the list of SSL-only servers.
- Disable SSL in your mail client.

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @SudiyaPradhan could you edit your answer includin essentisl part from the link so user can view it in stack. Only link is not a good answer because links can change.

Answer (score 0):

I could view packages but got the trust error when trying to install.

Found out that the Nuget package source url (nuget.org/api/v2/) routes through https://go.microsoft.com.  See nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1623.

The certificate path for that site starts with Baltimore CyberTrust Root.  That certificate was not being recognized.  Once I added it to my Trusted Root Certification Authorities, then the installation worked fine.  Get the certificate here:
www.cybertrust.ne.jp/SureServer/file/root_ca/BCTRoot.txt